# Debian 10 Upload speed issue

Tags: upload

I am using a small Lenovo i5 PC as a server. for some odd reason it's upload speed is capped at around `4.03 Mbit/s`

System:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) x86_64 
10E90002UK ThinkCentre M83 
Kernel: 5.5.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 
CPU: Intel i5-4590T (4) @ 3.000GHz
Ethernet Card: (eno1) Ethernet Connection I217-LM

Speed Test Result:
Download: 923.60 Mbit/s
Testing upload: 4.01 Mbit/s
```

Raspberry Pi 3B+ on the same network has exactly the same issue. It's upload speed is caped at `4.03 Mbit/s`

I have two routers, with 1 gigabit ports support. Tried both. Same result.

I have a Manjaro and another Debian 10 PC on the same network that do not have that problem.

I am on a symmetrical 1 Gigabit connection and other machines can use it.

I am suspecting Ethernet Card drivers. Any ideas?I217-LM

UPDATE: downloading the driver for I217-LM from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/60019/Intel-Ethernet-Connection-I217-LM) and running `sudo make install` did build and install the driver but did not solve the issue.

Comment: what speed do you get between the i5 and the other machines on the same network? Install ethtool and see what it says the negotiated speed is. Look to see if the routers are doing traffic shaping. See if you are getting errors reported by the NICs.

Comment: @icarus Thanks. Speed between machines on the same/local network is a full 1 Gigabit. When I run `sudo ethtool eno1 | grep Speed` I see this: `Speed: 1000Mb/s`. `ethtool` does not report any errors it seems? Routers don't seem to shape any traffic. I had many devices connected to them, both via WiFi and via Ethernet, and only two devices out of 10+ have this issue. Lenovo i5 Mini-Box and Raspberry Pi 3B+.

Comment: If you are getting full speed when doing LAN to LAN that pretty much rules out bad hardware (cables, router, NICs etc). Can you check a couple of files in /proc/sys/net/ipv4? tcp_window_scaling should have 1 in it, and that the three numbers in tcp_wmem are something like 4096 16384 4194304. This checks that at least you are offering to keep lots of data in flight.  Just to confirm, this is TCP and IPv4 we are working with - correct?

Comment: @icarus Thanks so much for your help. I did check the files: `tcp_window_scaling` 
has `1` in it and `tcp_wmem` has `4096    16384   4194304`. And yes, IPv4. It is strange that both machines (Lenovo i5 and RPi 3B+) have the same issue, running on a stable Debian 10. Another Lenovo laptop is on Debian rolling (testing) and it is just fine.

Comment: OK, clutching at straws now. What is the contents of tcp_congestion_control and is it different between the stable and rolling versions? For reference mine says "cubic". After this I think I am going to need a wireshark/tcpdump output.

Comment: There is a speedtest-cli bug in some version. To rule that out just download the newest version and retry. Bugreport: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/speedtest-cli/+bug/1828929 Git: https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/blob/master/README.rs

Comment: OMFG you are totally right! Sorry, for being stupid. All searches I did for 2 days never lead to this Bug. I do have a full speed indeed: https://ibit.ly/hFwU thank you all for your time. There were 3-4 other threads on the net about this with no resolve. I hope they find this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a speedtest-cli [bug](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/speedtest-cli/+bug/18289) in some version. Version that is in Debian Stable repos has this bug. You can download latest version from here https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli

Or add Testing repos and download it from there.